# Migration for static blocks to move from local to stagging

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, migration

I am working on Magento 1.7 and have very little experience with magento. I created few blocks and pages now I want to add them to staging site. but the staging Database is different form my local Database as there is some other peoples are also working on same project so what will the write way to migrate my local static blocks to staging site. any module or any database migration ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Only static block or with cms pages ?

Comment: few blocks and few new pages also

Answer (score 0):

First backup below tables from staging site.

Export below tables from local site and import it to staging site.

> `cms_page` and `cms_page_store`
>
> `cms_block` and `cms_block_store`

Comment: export & import tables as SQL dump?

Comment: Yes import and export it from phpmyadmin.

Comment: but problem with this if other team made any changes in these tables this will overwrite there changes and can be a problem

Comment: Then you have to import row only which you need to on staging.